# Using the Eclipse plug-in development environment to build a template how to write?

Tags: plugins

The first leg of the journey is to create a new plug-in project (File> New> Project> Plug-in Project). Please use the template. Ensure that dependencies between projects and org.eclipse.pde.ui. Once this is done, you can go to the Extensions plug-in editor tab, and then began to create a template.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing a answer to my question as a question!? Anyway that´s just a quotation from IBM!